# Daily Events in Fifth Gen

Tags: nintendo-ds, pokemon-fifth-generation

What are the daily events that I should be attending in Pokemon Black and White?

I'm mainly referring to items given out daily, swarm like events from 4th Gen, and daily battles. Feel free to include events that are weekly/seasonal in nature like the ice cream shop in Castelia City.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Serebii.net has a [list of daily and weekly events](http://serebii.net/blackwhite/dailyevent.shtml):

### Daily Events

- Swarms
- Massage (Castelia City)
- Musical Props (Opelucid City)
- Berry Clown (Castelia City)
- Ferris Wheel Battle (Nimbasa City)
- Heart Scale Lady (Drifveil City)
- Cynthia Battle (Undella Town)
- Furniture (Nacrene City)
- GameFreak Battle
- Opelucid City Battles
- Star Piece Rock (Pinwheel Forest)
- Sports Arenas Battles
- Black City Trainers / White City Items
- Royal Unova Battles
- Undella Villa Battles
- Patrat Game (Marvelous Bridge)
- Weather Stones (Route 8)
- Fossils (Twist Mountain Cave)
- Village Bridge Waiter
- Village Bridge Fisherman
- Treasure Hunter (Route 13)

### Weekly Events

- Musharna (Dreamyard, Fridays)
- Bianca Battle (Nuvema Town, Saturday)
- Casteliacone (Castelia City, Tuesdays)
- Anville Town - Lost Property
- Anville Town - Item Trades

Comment: Also, in each month (in-game Season) you can show the new Deerling form to a scientist on Route 6. At the end I think you get a Leaf Stone.